# Redis Module - Accessing Multiple Keys with Clustering in Mind

Tags: redis

I have a Redis module with a custom command that issues commands to two different keys at once.

The custom commands receives a key (e.g. `myKey`), and some values, and issues `HSET myKey_sd1 ...` and `ZADD myKey_sd2 ...` commands.

I wonder what would happen in a cluster configuration, where each key could exist in a separate node.

Right now, inside the module's custom command I enclosure the key that is given to me in `{` and `}`, so I end up issuing `HSET {myKey}_sd1` and `ZADD {myKey}_sd2`

Which works but I wonder if it's necessary.

I also wonder what happens if I receive a key that is already enclosed in curly brackets (because the user of the module wants to control the hash slot by himself) - e.g. `123_{myKey}`

Right now, I would still enclose this key in my own curly brackets when I issue the HSET and ZADD - `HSET {123_{myKey}}_sd1 ...` and `ZSET {123_{myKey}}_sd2`

In this case, as far as I know, Redis would compute the hash for `123_{myKey` which undermines the input of the user (since they didn't wish to enclose the `123_` part)

To fix it, I could have my custom command look for a `{` in the key that it received, if it didn't find a `{`, it would enclose the key in `{` and `}`, like I described above.
However, if it did find a `{`, it would leave the key as is, resulting in (in the case of the example above) `HSET 123_{myKey}_sd1 ...` and `ZADD 123_{myKey}_sd2` - which works both for the user and for the inner workings of the module.

So I wonder

1. Is enclosing the keys that I receive from the user in `{` and `}` the right way to support clustering?
2. If so, am I handling the case where the user provides a key which is already enclosed in `{` and `}` in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is enclosing the keys that I receive from the user in { and } the right way to support clustering?

The Redis Module cluster documentation is ["missing"](https://redis.io/topics/modules-intro#writing-commands-compatible-with-redis-cluster), but I believe it's the case that your module must make sure to use the same node as the key that was passed as an argument.

So, yes, you must use hash tags to ensure that your keys are using the same hash slot as the passed key.

> 2. If so, am I handling the case where the user provides a key which is already enclosed in { and } in the right way?

Your proposed fix (not your current implementation) is right. You must hash to the same slot as the key that is passed, which means respecting any specified hash slot.

Just make sure you're following the [exact algorithm](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags) for interpreting hash tags. You don't want any edge cases here.

Comment: This is the algorithm I was referring to (the ruby example code). By the way, the module api documentation in https://redis-module-redoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ talks about `RedisModule_IsKeysPositionRequest` and `RedisModule_KeyAtPos` in the context of writing commands that are compatible with cluster. I couldn't understand their purpose from reading `module.c`. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: @areller: I believe that the purpose is to allow the module to indicate which arguments to a command are keys. Redis needs to know that so it can route the command to the right node in a Cluster. I don't know any of the details, though.